# Highlight the selected text using Javafx WebView

Tags: java, webview, javafx-2, javafx

Is it possible to highlight the selected text in WebView using javafx 2.0 ? 
I want to make a program which can format the selected text in html file openeing in JavaFX2.0 WebView.

```
  I found *"yawas"* tool to highlight the webpage text in browsers but how to use 
  this facility in my javafx webview .Is it possible by executing the java script in 
  webview ?
```

Comment: yawas saves the highlight info as google bookmarks.  I'm not sure that is what you want.  ... but maybe it is not a bad idea since you won't have that information yourself since it will be on google's cloud.  You did not specify your ultimate goal.